# ETag applies to the resource at URI or the body in a response?

Tags: rest, http, etag

I'm not sure whether an ETag applies to the response body or the resource at the URL.

That's the same thing in a `GET`, thus uninteresting. But for other verbs, the latter would allow an ETag to be returned without a body.

i.e. a client were to `POST` an entity to `http://svc.net/items` and a `201 Created` with no body is returned, it could include the ETag of the collection of items at the URL posted to.

This very thing was outstanding as an ambiguity to clear up by IETF and Roy Fielding, but I don't know what ever happened to it or how to find out or even whether I'd understand their "legalese" anyway.

https://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/22

I'm especially interested in a citation as opposed to opinion on this.

Thanks for your help. Love you.

Update

It does have implications for `GET`. When getting page 1 of a collection of items, does the ETag cover page 1 or all the items?

That's interesting because a `POST` with an `If-Match` header is saying, "Only continue if the collection has not been changed", in which case the ETag needs to cover the whole collection.

At which point it brings about the question of whether page 1, as described by the URL `...?page=1` is the resource, or the entire collection beyond that addressed by the URL, is the resource?

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:** It might not be an answer, but it's too long for a comment.*

---

According to the [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), the current reference for conditional requests in HTTP 1.1, the `ETag` header field is applied to the *resource representation*.

The [ETag section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) states the following:

> [**2.3.  ETag**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3)
>
> The "ETag" header field in a response **provides the current entity-tag
> for the selected representation**, as determined at the conclusion of
> handling the request.  An entity-tag is an **opaque validator for
> differentiating between multiple representations of the same
> resource**, regardless of whether those multiple representations are
> due to resource state changes over time, content negotiation
> resulting in multiple representations being valid at the same time,
> or both.  An entity-tag consists of an opaque quoted string, possibly
> prefixed by a weakness indicator. [...]